# mvc Manupilate WebRequest Onlydisplay specific parts

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Loading An external webpage (html) into an string variable using the code below:

```
        WebClient webpage = new WebClient();
        string url = "<url to page>";
        //remove <div class="yr-footer lp_footer"/>
        //string html = webpage.DownloadString(url);//.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r","").Replace("\t","").Replace("\"","'");
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        string html = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

How do I manipulate the results (html variable) to hide all but the specific div's I would like to display?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Remove it after passing and redering the string to the view/partial view by adding jQuery in the view/partial view:

```
<script>
   $(".class1").remove();
   $(".class2").remove();
   $(".class3").remove();
   $(".class4").remove();
   $(".class5").remove();
</script>
```

Using the name will probably work just as well

```
<script>
   $("#Name1").remove();
   $("#Name2").remove();
   $("#Name3").remove();
   $("#Name4").remove();
   $("#Name5").remove();
</script>
```